# Trigonometric Ratios and Converse of Pythagoras Theorem Lemma

Tags: trigonometry, ratio

[image]

I am not quite sure what the question is asking here really.  I understand the Lemma.  Do I prove that $a^2+b^2=1$, using the given expressions for $a$ and $b$?

Thank you!

Comment: Please do not use pictures.

Comment: What is wrong with using a picture?  Please explain.  I did not see it anywhere in the rules that pictures are not permitted.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions) for some good arguments not to use pictures.

Comment: Thank you, fair comment!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to prove that $a^2+b^2=1$, using the given expressions for $a$ and $b$. You also need to show that $a$ and $b$ are positive (you'll see then why you need $\alpha < 45^\circ$).

Then, by applying the Lemma you get the conclusion of the exercise.

Comment: I am not quite sure why do I have to show that $a$ and $b$ are positive.  I thought because I end up having $a=\cos2\alpha$ and $b=\sin2\alpha$ It is to show that $2\alpha$ is an acute angle.

Comment: @PomPom The converse of the Lemma is saying "If $a,b$ are some pair of positive numbers and ...". And the point of the problem is that you can show that there exists some $\theta$ such that ..... without using trigonometry. The entire goal of this section/chapter seems to be to introduce $\cos$ and $\sin$ and their basic properties.. This means that you also need to avoid using more deep results.